# Near in its verb form

Tags: word-usage

Is it correct to say

> David does not near women.

Meaning that he does not go close to them or approach them.

Comment: David does not **go** near women.

Comment: It is grammatical but unidiomatic, since we typically near locations and states but not people.  Jim's revision, using *near* as a preposition, is more usual.

Comment: Yes, that's right. _Near_ (v) is most frequently encountered in phrases like _We're nearing the end, As you near the bridge,_ referring to transition on a path. As pointed out, this use does not have sense of _go near_, but rather _reach_.

Answer (score 1):

I expect you would have pretty much got your answer by now, but nevertheless, take a look at this definition of ***near as a verb*** from the [Cambridge Dictionaries](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/near_3):

> **near** *verb [I or T]*
>
> to get close to **something** in distance, time, or state:
>
> 1. I'm pleased to say the project is nearing completion.
> 2. As the wedding day neared, I started to have second thoughts about getting married.
> 3. The captain switched on the seat belt sign as we neared the airport.

As is mentioned in the definition and even in the comments, normally near is used as a verb when you refer to a specific point in time or location.

Synonyms of near as a verb, from [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/near[verb]) like  *belly up, close, close in, come up, draw on, near, nigh* would further give you an idea on how **near** can be used in several situations, depending on the context.

And last, to answer your question, though your sentence is *technically* correct, the ideal usage of near would be as @Jim suggested in his comment.

Answer (score -2):

Seems like it is proper in that usage: 
http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=near&allowed_in_frame=0

Since the 1500s, it's been used as a verb.

Answer (score -4):

*Near*, when used as a verb, must be included in a verb phrase such as *go near*. The current phrasing of the sentence would not be used in colloquial English.

However, the sentence

> David does not go near women.

is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: _The boat neared the dock_ contradicts your first statement.

Comment: In _go near_, _near_ is **not** used as a verb. So it has absolutely nothing to do with _near used as a verb_! You are saying that "A sword, when used for decoration, should be used to kill people."

Comment: @oerkelens OK, it sounds like something I'd say. But you've got me beat.